# Replacing strings one by one using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I'd love to replace a number of placeholder texts dynamically using javascript. Tried to use jquery filter and contain selector but didn't really get anywhere. Do you have an idea how these could be replaced?

```
<div class="container">
<h1>$$Insert text here$$</h1>
<div>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <div>$$Insert text here$$</div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="$$Insert text here$$"><br>
        <p>Here some other text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use an existing template engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example assuming if you have only one kind of place holder for study purpose:

```
var container = $('.container');
container.html(container.html().replace(/\$\$Insert text here\$\$/g,'mytext'))
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Pqpfa/2/

---

If you are trying to implement your own template engine, here is a bit more complex example where you can have different placeholder names:

html:

```
<div class="container">
<h1>$$pageTitle$$</h1>
<div>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <div>$$inputName$$</div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="please enter $$inputName$$"><br>
        <p>Here some other text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
var myClass = {};
myClass.pageTitle = 'my awsome page title';
myClass.inputName = 'your name';

var replaceFunc = function(match,p1){
    if (myClass[p1]){
        return myClass[p1]
    }
}

var container = $('.container');
container.html(container.html().replace(/\$\$(.*)\$\$/g, replaceFunc))
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kQH5F/1/

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use a template engine but you can acheve this even using pure JS

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('\\$\\$Insert text here\\$\\$','g'), 'replace it with');
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/tp9NY/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little practical example,
You could basically pass any model:

```
 <div class="container">
 <h1>Hi $$fname$$ $$lname$$</h1>
 <div>
 <p>My first paragraph.</p>
 <div>You are the <b>$$title$$</b> of <b> $$company$$ </b></div>
 <div>
  <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="$$salary$$"><br/>
    <p>Call us at $$phone$$</p>
</div>
</div>


 var myobj = {
  fname: 'Alex',
  lname: 'Shilman',
  title: 'CEO',
  company: 'Interactive Aim',
  phone: '(111)111-1111',
  salary: 10000000
  },
 makeView = function(myobj){
  for (var key in myobj){
   $('div.container').html($('div.container').html().replace('$$'+key+'$$',    myobj[key]));
  }
 };  

  makeView(myobj);
```

JSBin working example: http://jsbin.com/Oforipom/2/edit